# NET:HTTP headers ruby gem

Tags: ruby, http, header

I am trying to use the NET:HTTP gem to add an api-key to http header of a client, but it just doesn't seem to be working for some reason when I try and test it out.Basically the server requires the http header of the client or anything to have http_x_api header in order to serve the request.

Server code

```
   require 'sinatra'

   before do
     halt 400 if (env['API_KEY']) != 'wow'
  end

   get '/' do
     "boo"
   end
```

Client code

```
    require 'net/http'
    require 'uri'

    port = ENV['PORT'] || '7474'

    res = Net::HTTP.start('localhost', port )  { |h| h.get('/')} 
    res.add_field('api-key', 'wow')
    res.each_header do |key, value|
      p "#{key} => #{value}"
    end        
    puts (res.code == '200' && res.body == 'boo') ? 'OK' : 'FAIL'

    this the response i get back :=>

   "x-frame-options => sameorigin"
   "x-xss-protection => 1; mode=block"
   "content-type => text/html;charset=utf-8"
   "content-length => 0"
   "connection => keep-alive"
   "server => thin 1.5.0 codename Knife"
   "api-key => wow"
    FAIL
```

Answer (score 0):

On the server, the HTTP header variables in `env` are prefixed with `HTTP_`, so you need to check `env['HTTP_API_KEY']`. From [the documentation](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/SPEC.html):

> `HTTP_` Variables:    Variables corresponding to the client-supplied HTTP request headers (i.e., variables whose names begin with HTTP_). The presence or absence of these variables should correspond with the presence or absence of the appropriate HTTP header in the request.